# Standalone application with backend as sql server 'runtime' only?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I don't know the proper term for sql server "runtimes"  but yeah.. 
I have an application made in VB.Net, it's already working fine but on the database part I have to configure it manually, I design the database tables on management studio, which, in turn, wouldn't allow my application to be installed on another PC without me manually adding the database tables on the management studio..

As a solution for this, I have decided to make the application do the database table construction itself. The program will: 
**Create a database

Create database tables

Create columns with primary keys and relationships 

Create user instances per PC**

my question is, is this possible without installing sql server management studio (SSMSEE) and installing only the sql server "runtimes"? [This](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21844) is the link for the "runtimes".

Comment: You don't know the proper term for it, and yet you're able to supply a link to a page that has a title telling you exactly what you're downloading?

Comment: I know that it is sqlserver 2005 but I don't know how to name its contents.. on Crystal Reports they call it "runtimes" when you only need its function on application runtime.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a local database as part of your application, to be installed along side your application?  Because Visual Studio can do that; just add a .MDF to your project and edit the tables in Visual Studio.  The .MDF file will then be included in whatever installer (.MSI for example) your Visual Studio solution produces.  At the very least every PC running your software would need an instance of SQL Server Express Edition installed to run it (the software you've linked to).